# How do receivers of broadcast messages keep track of control + payload

Tags: error-handling, communication, packet, payload

When transmitting a message, you have payload + control data.
While control data is there to help a receiver filter the right data, payload is just there as a state in time.
Given that there are uncountable amounts of data being broadcasted from all kinds of devices, how does a receiver know at any time that this data is meant for it and not another device?
Example:

```
time1: control
time2: payload
```

or even

```
time1: control-part1
time2: control-part2
...
timen: payloadn
```

How does a receiver of control-part2 know about control-part1 and is able to assign payloadn to control-part1?

In addition to this, communication might be encrypted and even if not, it probably looks like this:

```
time1: control-part1
time1.5: payload x by some random other device
time2: control-part2
...
timen: payloadn
timen+1: control by some random other device
```

And if it's encrypted how does it know where the next bit of information is.

An application I think of are light-modulations by distance measurement devices. The device basically has to wait for a full sequence to come back. But there is a lot of light diffraction going on, interfering with the receptor. Why does it just work?

Answer (score 0):

If the broadcast message is not encrypted the receiver just see all the broadcast messages. In the case of [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol), when a device want to know the MAC address of other device send a [arp request](https://www.javatpoint.com/arp-request#:%7E:text=ARP%20%28Address%20Resolution%20Protocol%29%20Request%20ARP%20stands%20for,%28Ethernet%29%20by%20providing%20the%20other%20device%27s%20MAC%20address.) (broadcast) and the target device respond because in the ARP packet there is a field to identify it.

On the other hand, in a case of broadcast encryption there is a system to distribute keys and then the receiver device that have the that can decrypt the message just decrypted and can access the information ([Broadcast Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_encryption)).

So, when is done a broadcast and is not encrypted the packet has some information to identify the target host and when the message is encrypted there are first a distribution of keys and then only the devices that have the keys can see the information decrypted.

I hope that this help!